# How to navigate to sibling in Angular 4 using relative navigation?

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular4-router

I am facing issue with Router navigation with lazy load. I would appreciate if anyone clarify the issues below.Thank you.

app-routing.module

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
{ path: Details, loadChildren: 'pathToDetailsModule'}
];
```

details.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
  path: '', component : DetailsComponent,
   childern : [
    {path: '' , redirectTo: prodType},
    {path: prodType , loadChildren: pathtoModuleProd},
    {path: CusDetails, loadChildren: pathtoModuleCustomer},
    {path: EmpDetails, loadChildren: pathToModuleEmp}
   ]
},
];
```

Initially when I click Details (app-routing.module), DetailsModule gets load and DetailsComponent and gets redirect to prodType by default. My page displays ProdType(child). Now I want to navigate to CusDetails.

## Issues:

#1.

At this point

```
currentRoute =  this.activatedRoute.snapshot.url[0].path
```

is giving result `Details`(parent) instead of `prodType`(child). Is lazy loaded module adding empty path?
Now I'm on the Child - `prodType` and want to navigate to child - `CusDetails` ). As per my knowledge to load sibling CusDetails-

```
this.router.navigate(['../CusDetails'],{relativeTo: this.route}); // expected
```

but in my case I'm using below code to load sibling because currentRoute is `Details`(parent).

```
this.router.navigate(['CusDetails'], { relativeTo: this.route});
```

Why currentRoute is giving result `Details` instead of `prodType`?
I would appreciate explanation.

#2.

Now say I am in CusDetail and I want to navigate to its sibling EmpDetails using

```
this.router.navigate(['../EmpDetails'],{relativeTo: this.route});
```

and we get `localhost:4200/Details/CusDetails/EmpDetails`
but if I use below code it works fine.

```
this.router.navigate(['../../EmpDetails'],{relativeTo: this.route});
```

Why is it not working with single?

```
'../'
```

I would appreciate explanation.

Answer (score 7):

Up to Angular v6.x this is [a known issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13011) with 'relative link resolution' in router navigation.

The unintuitive way that the relative router navigation works is a bug that the angular team are aware of.

The main issue here is that routing is done based on the the router config 'tree' and not the URL path. The routing config tree is often different due to componentless nodes and lazy loaded modules which add extra levels when navigating (hence the extra `../`'s). [(see here for a more detailed explanation)](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13011#issuecomment-364815580)

This bug has actually [already been fixed (docs)](https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions#relativeLinkResolution) in v6.1 but to avoid breaking all the applications that are already using extra `../`'s the fix is behind a feature flag. [(see PR discussion here)](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/22394#issuecomment-404248920)

To enable the corrected relative link resolution behaviour you just have to set the `relativeLinkResolution` setting  in `ExtraOptions` to 'corrected'

i.e.

```
 RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { relativeLinkResolution: 'corrected' })
```

Correcting this behaviour represents a breaking change therefore the corrected setting will be the default from v7 onwards (expected to be released within the coming weeks - Oct 2018).

Comment: Just came across this issue... It's still not the default behaviour in Angular 10.
Thanks for providing this solution!

Comment: It seems now the default behavior in Angular 11

Answer (score -1):

The router supports directory-like syntax in a link parameters list to help guide route name lookup:

./ or no leading slash is relative to the current level.

../ to go up one level in the route path.

You can combine relative navigation syntax with an ancestor path. If you must navigate to a sibling route, you could use the ../ convention to go up one level, then over and down the sibling route path.

For more information just go through the Relative navigation topic in https://angular.io/guide/router